# Uncaught: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have included jquery and bootstrap.min.js file in my footer section or it means i have my all script tag at the bottom of the code. But when i am loading my page the browser console throw an error says : **Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery.**
I am including these files locally like below:-

```
</footer>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/ems_ci/assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/ems_ci/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why put it footer?why not in header?

Comment: are you sure the path `http://127.0.0.1/ems_ci/assets/js/jquery.js` is valid

Comment: what does pasting this in the browser console show: `if (window.jQuery) {  
   console.log('jQuery is loaded');
} else {
    console.log('jQuery is not loaded');
}`

Comment: try to give a better link to your js file. The link may be broken, that's a common issue that you get. Just try to look into it thank you.

Comment: I have both jquery/bootstrap file in order like --
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -- 
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: ok then go to your function.php file and try to give a link for your js file in that like
`wp_enqueue_script('jquery.min.js',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.min.js');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's uncommon to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for a file path. Use `relative path` instead.

Regarding script position: you can leave them in the footer, that will speed up page loading, but make sure any JavaScript code you execute is AFTER jquery/bootstrap in the dom.
And don't forget to wrap your code inside a `document ready` jquery function

Comment: @Enrico- I have my files like -- <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Are you doing that in purpose? Also, i suppose that will not work, Because 127.0.0.1 will look for jquery on the client machine, not the server

Answer (score 0):

To begin, you must change the location of the tag 'script' into the tag 'head'. after this, you must change the location of your javascript scripts to your project directory. Finally, you change the value of the 'src' attribute to:
Ex:

- src="../js/jquery.js"
- src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"